# insert multiple records in one table based on id column in another table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two tables A and B 
Table A will have following structure

```
A_Id | record1 | record 2|
------------------------------
123|  fname    |    lname|
```

Records in table B should be added referencing Table A

```
B_Id |A_id | somerecord1| somerecord2|
--------------------------------------
1    |123  |  email1     | phone1
2    |123  |  email2     | phone1
```

How can I insert these records using a SP in a single attempt .Am new to this will appreciate your help .

Comment: So you need to insert all records in one Stored Procedure Call?  Can all values passed as parameters  or xml to stored procedure? Or are they taken somewhere?

Comment: Yes , in my SP , I am passing all the values that need to be inserted in Table A and Table B as two different table value parameters, Now once inserted , I need to use the A_ID and populate data in Table B

Answer (score 0):

In you SP Body write something like this

```
declare @a_id int

insert into A (record1, record2 )
select @fname, @lname

select @a_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into B (A_id, somerecord1, somerecord2)
select @a_id, @email1, @phone1 union all
select @a_id, @email2, @phone2 union all
select @a_id, @email3, @phone3
```

Comment: Thanks @fly_ua , am passing the content of the Table B in TVP as below 
Email | Phone
------------------
email 1| phone 1
email 2| phone2
email 3| phone3